# Change TabBar Items after changing app language from inside of app

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uitabbar

I have an app and from inside of it I am changing its language.
Language getting properly updated to other screens by changing `UIView` appearance.

```
Localize.setCurrentLanguage("ar")
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

I'm not able to get control back in my `tabcontrolle`r file. `TabBar` is custom created. I checked with `awakefromNib()` but it is not getting invocated every time. Is there any tab bar method where I can get control when it appears every time or is there any way to change language of tab bar item titles?

Comment: Did you try this? `tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers?.reversed()`

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I tried it. With this my controllers are getting reversed but tab bar items name are not changing, they remains same. So unable to properly visulise that controller are getting reversed.

Comment: How have you created the tabbar controller? Using storyboard or programatically?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Its programmatically created. I updated the code of how its created. I am invocating this method in viewdidLoad().

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I reloaded my rootviewcontroller window and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

After changing app language in your VC create and call function localizeTabBar():

```
func localizeTabBar() {
    tabBar.items![0].title = "1tab".localized
    tabBar.items![1].title = "2tab".localized
    tabBar.items![2].title = "3tab".localized
    tabBar.items![3].title = "4tab".localized
}
```

For .localized use [this String Extension](https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/app-localization-tips-with-swift-4e9b2d9672c9)

Answer (score 0):

Or something like that:

```
func localizeTabBar() {
    tabBar.items?.enumerated().forEach{ (index, item)  in
        item.title = "\(index)tab".localized
    }
}
```

For .localized use this [String Extension](https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/app-localization-tips-with-swift-4e9b2d9672c9)